# Button image transparent when added to view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I'm making a custom view to display a simple star rating system in my app. Each star is a UIButton that has a specific star image-file set as its image. Everything works fine in storyboard but when I run the app on a device each star image is slightly transparent.

When I set the background color of the buttons themselves, they are 100% opaque yet the images are still slightly transparent. Any reason why that same button's image wouldn't be opaque? I just want the stars to always be opaque and not dependent on background.

I just joined SO so I don't have enough reputation to post images yet but here's a link to an image that might explain the issue a bit better: [photo](https://flic.kr/p/reSpNZ)

Basic code for the custom UIView:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.opaque = YES;
    [self drawStars];
}

- (void)drawStars {
    float imagePadding = self.padding;
    CGFloat starWidth = self.selectedStarImage.size.width;

    for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < self.totalStars; counter++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(counter * (imagePadding + starWidth), 0, starWidth, starWidth)];

        button.opaque = YES;

        if (counter >= self.rating) {
            [button setImage:self.starImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else {
            [button setImage:self.selectedStarImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [self addSubview:button];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag=counter;
    }
}

- (void)updateStars
{
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self drawStars];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're seeing? Also, might want to check if the images themselves are transparent (.png supports transparency) and that the button's background color property is non-transparent (e.g., white).

Comment: ANSWER: simple issue of having the buttons disabled on some views. button.enabled = NO will make the button's image slightly transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen that the alpha of view on which you are adding the buttons as subviews could be lesser than one.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to first change the image of star because its background it transparent that is the problem and check the background color of button.
Or 
you can create whole transparent image and set proper background color which you want. 
These images are not proper. or check it by using another images.